# Facebook app_data

Tags: facebook

Can someone explain to me how to use facebook app_data which is part of the signed request?

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

The documentation is vague. I can't figure out how to actually use the app_data field. I want to be able to pass the app data to the app when it is added to a page so that the content displayed on it is relevant to the Facebook page.

for example I want a user profile on my site to only be displayed on that users facebook page. To do so I want to send the user ID to the fb signed request when the user adds the app to their page. Then anytime the page is visited I will pull the app data and run some php to display the correct profile.

Can I do this with the app_data or is this not possible?

Comment: +1 good question. You can also comment now, ask for clarifications to my answer if required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the documentation that you have cited

**App Data is**

> A JSON string containing the content of a query string parameter also called app_data. **Usually specified when the application built the link to pass some data to itself.** Only available if your app is an iframe loaded in a Page tab.

So app data is useful **only** when your application has **generated a link** that some user will click and follow through to your app on some Facebook page.

And if a user is **visiting some page (and the app tab) directly**, then you won't get the app_data field.

Once a user has installed your app (and has given your app minimum permissions) on any one of their pages, you always have the `page_id` and `user_id` fields in the `signed_request` that Facebook will send to your app, both in canvas apps (no `page_id` field) and page tab apps.

For what you want to do, you can just read the `signed_request` and then find out the `page_id` and display data accordingly, you do not even have to use user_id.

Hope this answers your question. Do ask for clarifications, if required.

Comment: thanks, I guess I'll have to just use the page id then. I needed to establish a relationship between my content and the facebook page and was hoping I could feed the app installed on that page with the app_data per a link I would provide for each user with the app_data appended.

Comment: you are welcome, you just need to store your data with respect to page_ids, so you have relationship between **page_id (Facebook page) and content** . Nothing to get worried about.