# How to set app_data with facebook pagetab dialog url?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to set app_data to a specific tab page. So a facebook user who clicks the page tab will have the app_data available.

I was trying to add app_data to the pagetab dialog url

I tried the following urls:

[www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/artware/?app_data=aa](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&redirect_uri=https://apps.facebook.com/artware/?app_data=aa)

[www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&next=https://apps.facebook.com/artware/?app_data=a](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&next=https://apps.facebook.com/artware/?app_data=a)

[www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&next=https://jbartfb.herokuapp.com/?app_data=a](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&next=https://jbartfb.herokuapp.com/?app_data=a)

[www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&redirect_uri=https://jbartfb.herokuapp.com/?app_data=a](http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=290672084311996&redirect_uri=https://jbartfb.herokuapp.com/?app_data=a)

none of them worked for me.

thanks,
shai

Comment: check out my answer at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646589/facebook-app-data/8647623#8647623 , it might help you.

Comment: Thanks. So you actually say I can not do it! "So app data is useful ONLY when your application has generated a link ...". 
Any idea about facebook policy about this strange limitation? Any ideas about workarounds?

Comment: if that answer helped you, i would like you to upvote it(the answer i linked to, and not just the comment here), that gives me points! about the workaround, can you give more details as to what you want to do exactly? i haven't heard of the pagetab dialog, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: try to search your app_data in $facebook->getSignedRequest();

Answer (score 1):

You redirect URIs may not contain query params. However: When you redirect to a canvas app (look like you do) you can always use rewrite rules to pass params. For example:

https://apps.facebook.com/artware/landing/install/param1/param2

Everything after your base URL (https://apps.facebook.com/artware/) is just appended to the url of your canvas app. So if your canvas URL is https://mydomain.com/myapp/ the previously mentioned landing URL would load https://mydomain.com/myapp/landing/install/param1/param2 inside the IFrame. From there you can redirect the user to whatever URL you like, query params and all.

Comment: Nice idea. I'll try it.
I was also thinking about changing the page properties, maybe the page info.

Can I save my params inside the page as custom properties? even manually...

Comment: Well, all those properties are public so it really depends on what you want to store there. I guess it would look kinda weird if there would be a JSON-encoded config object in the page's about section... ;)