# Constant querystring arguments in Page Tab URL

Tags: url, iframe, query-string, facebook-iframe

I want to point my Page Tab to a URL with querystring arguments like this:

```
http://domain.com/page.php?arg=CONSTANT
```

arg's value is a constant so I'm not trying to pass any dynamic data from the facebook page to my PHP page. It's just supposed to be a constant URL, with a constant querystring parameter.

I'm having problems getting this to work (nothing is shown on the facebook page tab), however when I use an URL without querystring parameters like this:

```
http://domain.com/page.php
```

it works right.

I couldn't find any information in the documentation saying that it's impossible to use URLs with querystring arguments. Is it? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer lives in the something facebook calls app_data in the signed_request specifically made for page tab apps.  See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not interested in an alternative way to pass the arguments. I really need the iframe to get the content of a specific URL which includes specific (and constant) querystring parameters.
Basically, my question is if it possible to have the equivalent of:
    <iframe src="domain.com/page.php?arg=CONSTANT"/>
in a facebook page tab.

Comment: There is no alternate for app_data, that is the reason why Facebook added it to their API.  Otherwise if there was an alternative, then why would have they wasted dev cycles on something that can easily be done another way?

Comment: I believe these are two different features.
app_data documentation: "Usually specified when the application built the link to pass some data to itself." 
And as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646589/facebook-app-data "if a user is visiting some page (and the app tab) directly, then you won't get the app_data field" it is completely different from what I need. thanks anyway.
I have solved the problem by creating a new php page in my webserver which then redirects the user to the page I want. URL rewrite might be useful too but I haven't done it yet.

Comment: hmm, interesting question. although not solving the problem, the following comments ended up answering my question: "is it possible to call a specific URL with querystring parameters?". the answer given was "no" so I probably should mark this as accepted. thank you for the reminder.