# How can I pass some values to my facebook canvas app in a query string?

Tags: php, facebook, get, query-string

I have developed a facebook canvas app which posts to users newsfeeds and I want to be able to allow users to click on the link in the newsfeed and be taken to my app along with some data that will be presented in the app (for example by passing it in the querystring).

When I create the link that will be posted on user's newsfeed I set the link field to -

`http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/?datatopass=mydata`

This works, when a user clicks this link the browser directs them to that link. However I cannot access the $_GET['datatopass'] variable (using PHP) and it appears to be blank. I have tried using javascript to output the window.location variable and I don't see my passed querystring, even though I see the url as it is above in my browser address bar. What I do see is the site url that i set up in the facebook developer app and the **state** and **code** params that facebook uses. It has stripped my **datatopass** param that I wanted to be able to read when my app launched.

So ... how can I pass along the data that I want to send? I know there is an app_data field if you are using signed_request but as I understand it this is only good for apps that sit in a Tab of a Page. I am using the iFrame canvas app method.

When I look at my apache server's access logs I can see that there is a POST entry for my site url address with my appended querystring -

```
my.domain.com 123.456.7.890 - - [23/Feb/2012:14:21:19 +0000] "POST /facebookapp/?datatopass=mydata HTTP/1.1" 200 300 "http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/?datatopass=mydata" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
```

Followed by a GET entry -

```
my.domain.com 123.456.7.890 - - [23/Feb/2012:14:21:20 +0000] "GET /facebookapp/directory/?state=99226fiawhoidhaoia09809a085d94832&code=ahfakshdlkfhalksj.... HTTP/1.1" 200 27094 "http://my.domain.com/facebookapp/?play=asd" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0"
```

My apologies I dont really understand what the above is doing but hoped it would be useful extra information in helping to answer this.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook allows you to pass data via an app_data variable.  This variable is part of the signed request and is a json encoded string.  So an example might go like this:

```
 top.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com/pages/PAGENAME/PAGE_ID?sk=APP_ID&app_data=MYDATA";
```

This app_data variable becomes part of the Facebook signed request.  More information can be found here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/
You simply parse the signed request and you can then access the data via the app_data as the documentation shows:

```
 function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

      // decode the data
      $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
      $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

      if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
          error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
          return null;
      }

      // check sig
      $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
      if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
          error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
          return null;
      }

      return $data;
 }

 function base64_url_decode($input) {
      return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
 }
```

So then you can call the function and access the app_data like this it with something like this:

```
 <?php 
      $signed_request = parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret);
      $signed_request['app_data'] = MYDATA;
 ?>
```

Comment: That's strange.  It seems to be working for me still.  Is your app_data in a json_encoded string?  I don't know if these posts will help: [facebook-app-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646589/facebook-app-data) [another post here] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801807/facebook-fan-page-app-pass-string-to-app-data-and-retrieve)

Comment: From our end, it looked like their sharing functionality went down when they made their daily push at about 7pm EDT.  I wonder if that could have affected anything with this functionality as well.

Comment: I just realized you posted this on how to pass data to a page, not an app.

Answer (score 1):

You may need a / after the app name in the URL i.e..

`http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/?datatopass=mydata`

Comment: Hi - yes that was a misprint on my part I should have added the / in my question - but my browser will add this for me if I do not so i see the same behaviour regardless. When i configured the app on facebook I have Site URL = http://my.domain.com/facebookapp/index.php and canvas url = http://my.domain.com/facebookapp/ Canvas page is http://apps.facebook.com/myappname (no slash but then facebook fills this in for you).. Ive updated my question but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using rewrite engine? Facebook supports it, so a link like apps.facebook.com/myapp/data/anotherdata is valid.
Try it this way and print_r($_REQUEST) to chek if it is passed.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook used to allow GET parameters for canvas apps. These parameters were passed via the IFRAME tag that Facebook used to embed your app. However, this posed a security risk because all scripts included by the page (css, js...) have access to these parameters via the Referrer. As a result, all apps were required to migrate to using POST parameters instead. Please see this document for additional info:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/

Comment: Ok but I still dont see how I can pass variables in a querystring - I want to update a user's status with a link that when they click on it will launch my app and preconfigure it with the data in the querystring part of the url. So is it just not possible to do this?

Comment: Variables in the querystring of a URL are GET parameters. Facebook is is stripping out these variables automatically. You may see them in the address bar, but they are not being included in the IFRAME tag which is what really matters. What you are trying to do is certainly possible, it just takes a little bit more coding. For example, you may replace a traditional anchor link by using a FORM tag with hidden fields for the parameters that you need. Another option is to use javascript to automatically convert traditional links to POST, see here for example:
http://code.google.com/p/postlink/

Comment: Thanks Gil, I was coming round to thinking that I might have to do what I think you are suggesting which is to link to a script (hosted on my server) which converts the querystring params to a form and then submits it to my canvas app - is this what you are meaning?

Comment: I think that what you're saying is that the "link" is not already hosted on your server. In that case you're suggestion sounds reasonable to me. For example, if you wanted to post a link on your facebook news feed like http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/?datatopass=mydata then instead you should post a link to http://myserver.com/myapp/redirector.php?datatopass=mydata. That redirector.php script will redirect by repackaging the query string parameters as a POST request to http://apps.facebook.com/myappname/. But, if the link is actually hosted on your server then the redirector is redundant.

Comment: yes the link is on a news feed, I want users of my app on facebook to click on a link in their newfeed and be directed to the app and pass along some data. I'll keep investigating the redirect post solution. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Any values you pass into the apps.facebook.com link will be passed into your canvas page as well. The one exception is the `signed_request`, which Facebook POSTs to your canvas page.

Comment: thanks @dtbarne. This one should be marked as answer.