# Facebook fan page app pass string to app_data and retrieve

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps, facebook-app-requests

Hi i have a multiple page facebook fan page app in asp.net c#. how do i set and retrieve that app_data querystring? is this part of the signedrequest or the actual url of the fan page? will there be cross domian issues in getting this in safari and ie?

i can get the signed_request using the following:

```
 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(signedRequest))
{
    dynamic SignedRequestData;
    var DecodedSignedRequest = FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest.Data;
    SignedRequestData = DecodedSignedRequest
```

so basically on the first page i want to get the signed_reqeuest using the above and then append this to the url in app_data querystring. on all other requests i can then get this and use those values to check user status, liked, logged in etc. This way i think it will stop the cross domain cookie issues in safari. anyone agree or disagree with this?

has anyone done this?

cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `app_data` as:

`https://www.facebook.com/{page_id}?sk=app_{app_id}&app_data={"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`

You can pass multiple values into `app_data` and it will be returned in the `signed_request` to your actual page as (POST data).

What you should really do is get the `signed_request` on first page load from POST, and add it to the URL of your app as `...?signed_request={signed_request_string}`. Every page should then pass this around in the URL so you can easily check the `like` and `admin` status from any sub-page. You don't need to use `app_data` for this. And in any case, the data will be lost after the any subsequent click / redirect in your app.

Comment: Niraj.. do you know something related to the problem that app_data is removed in the wall posts seen on timeline? http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/322852237799370/

Comment: I haven't come across this issue myself, but then I haven't tried to do the same thing. Try using the URL shortener?

Comment: Well, if you try generating a link from an iframe app, which contains app_data, then this is removed from the link when viewed from timeline. I did the bit.ly thing, with redirection, etc. but it is a very dirty option. When sharing that, it doesn't get the icon, etc. Thanks!