# parameters removed from facebook ad url

Tags: facebook, parameters, facebook-ads-api

I use facebook advertising to promote my app.
To be able to track from which url's ad new players come from
i add a parameter with a specific number to each url used in facebook advertising.

Example :  https://apps.facebook.com/myapp?ori=123456

sometimes the parameter is stripped from the url by facebook
and a new user is seen by the app as coming from  https://apps.facebook.com/myapp
losing information on the way.

How to do to be sure to get a parameter transmitted by facebook to the app
through the facebook advertising ?

Comment: You may want to try using app_data instead. Check out this post here, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646589/facebook-app-data