# Passing app_data within an Page_tab

Tags: facebook, url-parameters

I want to populate a page-tab in such a way, that it gets a unique identifier.

In other words: I want to use one app-id for multiple page-tabs which, depending on that given identifier, should display different content.

I hoped that was possible with app_data since the *doc* says:

> In addition, your app will also receive a string parameter called app_data as part of signed_request if an app_data parameter was set in the original query string in the URL your tab is loaded on.

I tried it like that, but my signed request does not contain my data:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=APPID&app_data={'test': '1'}&next=REDIRECT
```

I know I could use the page_id, but then I can not use the same app_id several times on one page

Comment: If this is correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646589/facebook-app-data/8647623#8647623 it does not seem to be possible, right?

Comment: You can't use the same app on the same page multiple times, this is not dependent on whether or not you use the details in the signed_request, it's just not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Igy](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/users/21062/igy) has pointed out, you can't have multiple Page Tabs with a single App ID or a single App can't be placed multiple times on a **single Page**.Although you can a single App as a Page tab on multiple **different** Pages.